# Getting model state via rospy

Tags: rospy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello there,
In my reinforcement learning simulation I am trying to get the pose of one of the models to use it for some calculations. Although I think I am using correct methods, the results are not what I want. Here is what the data for the model looks like in Gazebo:

[image: gazebo model description]

Here what interests me is the model pose.

And when I use the rosservice call on this model to get the state, [same as in the tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_comm&cat=connect_ros#GetModelStateExample) it returns the correct pose. But when I am trying to use rospy, I get the pose of a link, which stays the same. Here is the code that I use to do this:

```
self.model_coordinates = rospy.ServiceProxy( '/gazebo/get_model_state', GetModelState)
self.object_coordinates = self.model_coordinates("8115RC_V2", "8115RC_V2")
z_position = self.object_coordinates.pose.position.z
y_position = self.object_coordinates.pose.position.y
x_position = self.object_coordinates.pose.position.x
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18372/getting-model-state-via-rospy/) by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've found an answer, the second parameter to model_coordinates needs to be an empty string.

---

Originally posted by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) with karma: 35 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljburtz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7170/ljburtz/) on 2020-06-18**:
precision about the "empty string":
that second argument to the service client call (model_coordinates() in this case) represents the relative_entity_name
As the docs say :
"leave empty or "world" will use inertial world frame"
http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/gazebo_msgs/html/srv/GetModelState.html